# How to dynamically update text within a modal for each row JQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, modal-dialog

So I have a table of appointments per user and for each row there is a button called 'Actions'. When this button is clicked a modal pops up with a series of actions for that particular row/booking i.e. complete the booking or cancel etc. Within that modal there are tabs for each of these actions. One of those actions is 'Adjust Payment' where the user is able to adjust the final amount the customer has to pay for their appointment.

However the new amount they enter has to be higher than the current amount. Here's what I have so far:

The modal:

```
<div id="myTabContent" class="tab-content" style="font-weight: 200; font-family: MontserratExtraLight;" >   
<div class="tab-pane fade active in" id="adjustPayment<?php echo $i; ?>">
<?php

    <h2 style="float: left;" class="modal-title text-color">Adjust Payment</h2>
    <br><br>
    <p style="float: left;font-size: 15px;">Adjust Patients Final Payment</p>
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $bookings[$i]['id']; ?>"/>
    <input type="hidden"  name="customer_id" value="<?php echo $bookings[$i]['customer_id']; ?>"/>
    <input type="hidden"  name="booking_id" value="<?php echo $bookings[$i]['booking_id']; ?>"/>
    <input hidden type="hidden" name="date_time_from" value='<?php echo $bookings[$i]['date_time_from']; ?>' />


    <br><br>
    <p style="float: left;font-size: 15px;">You can adjust the final amount the customer has to pay below. </p>
    <br>
    <p style="text-align: center;font-size: 15px;"> Please Enter a New Payable Amount (inc. Add-ons): </p> <br>
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="form-group div-style">
            <small class="help">
                <span style="display:none;" id="message_c" class="message" role="alert">The new payable amount must be higher than the previous payable amount.</span> </small>
                <span style="font-size:20px; font-weight:bold;">   <?php echo CURRENCY_SYMBOL."&nbsp;" ?>  </span>
                <input type="text" class="input form-control main-color input-lg new_payable_amount" id="new_payable_amount" style="background: #f4f4f4; width:30%; float:center; display: inline-block; font-weight:bold;" onkeypress="return (event.charCode !=8 && event.charCode ==0 || ( event.charCode == 46 || (event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57)))" name="new_payable_amount"><br>

        </div>
    </div>


   <br><br>
     <p style="float:left;font-size: 15px;"><strong>Note:</strong> You can only enter an amount higher than the current amount payable by the patient which is:</p>
     <p id="old_payable_amount" class="old_payable_amount" style="text-align: center; font-size: 26px; font-weight: bold; "><?php echo CURRENCY_SYMBOL."&nbsp;". number_format($bookings[$i]['payment'] / 100, 2); ?> </p>

     <input type="button" id="adjustAmount" class="button btn-black btn-system btn button-lg adjustAmount" style="margin-top: 10px; border-radius:0px; width: 30%; margin-bottom: 0%;" value="Adjust">
               <?php //} ?>

             </div>
```

The JQuery:

```
$('.new_payable_amount').on('keyup', function() {
    //  var new_payable = document.getElementById('new_payable_amount').value;
    var new_payable = $(".new_payable_amount").val();
    //var old_payable = document.getElementById('old_payable_amount').innerHTML;
    var old_payable = $(".old_payable_amount").html();

    old_payable = old_payable.replace(/[^\d\.]/g, '');

    if(new_payable <= old_payable){
        //  document.getElementById('message_c').innerHTML="The new payable amount must be higher than the previous payable amount." +old_payable +" " +new_payable;
        $(".message").html("The new payable amount must be higher than the previous payable amount." +old_payable +" " +new_payable);
        //  document.getElementById('message_c').style.display = 'block';
        $(".message").css("display", "block");
        $("#adjustAmount").attr("disabled", true);

    }else {
        //  document.getElementById('message_c').innerHTML= "";
        $(".message").html("Pass ");
        //document.getElementById('message_c').style.display = 'block';
        $(".message").css("display", "block");

        $("#adjustAmount").attr("disabled", false);
    }
  });
```

The problem is that the JQuery is returning the data from the first row and the actions within the jquery script only affect the modal for the first row. At first I was using id's to retrieve the data and components but then turned to classes as there are multiple rows this however, did not work either. The current code returns the 'old_payable_amount' from the first row, the 'new_payable_amount' entered on the first row is displayed throughout all rows and the message is does not update dynamically for every row.

Additionally once the 'Adjust' button is clicked I want it to open a confirmation dialogue but, instead of using the confirm I have created a modal which opens up correctly for each time adjust is clicked. I would like to pass a value through to this modal and was wondering how you could possible do so? I have tried to via href but the modal doesn't open as expected unless I use jquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You could use `$(this)` to get the value from the one you `keyup` on instead of `$('.new_payable_amount')` - this gonna be collection... so you change value of every element with this class.

   Use `$(this).val()` and `$(this).html()`
   to update and to get data.
2. If your input would be type `number` you can use `min` and `max` property without engaging js

**Updated**

3. Your "Additionaly ask". You need to somehow relate your modals.

In your code I can see

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $bookings[$i]['id']; ?>"/>
```

Use this `id` in the `id` of your confirmation modal. like

```
<div id="updated_amount_<?php echo $bookings[$i]['id']; ?>"></div>
```

and then you could update it knowing the id...

```
var update_id = $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().find("input[name='id']");
$("updated_amount_"+update_id).html(new_payable);
```

It could be better way, but thats what I thought on fast

There is also question of how the modal-dialog got attached. Is it rendered in html from the beginning or is it attached by js everytime.

Comment: This worked for entering a new value for every row however, the old_payable_amount is in most case different for every booking (row) and the correct value isn't being pulled instead, the value for the first row gets pulled in.

Also for the second part the modal is html and gets called and opened on button click of the adjustAmount button. The data I want to pass through to the pop-up modal which will act as a confirmation dialogue is the $i variable so that I'm able to store the values such as booking[$i]['id'] and so on..

Comment: First of all I dont see any `old_payable_amount` class in the html. Anyway you should find that class from the `$(this)` using `.parents()` or `next()` or any other function that jquery provides. It's adviceable to learn more about jquery functions if you use it :). About last case I will update answer

Comment: Oh sorry, I've updated the code to add it in I must have missed it out

Comment: @Hydra Did you figure it out on your own?